# Ubuntu, persistence and casper loop file

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, files

I have made a bootable linux USB key with Lili Usb Creator using Ubuntu Voyager 14.04 i386 iso.
No problem with this program.
MyLiveLinux work very speedly, no error, no driver problem on all my computers.

As My Usb stick is a 32 Go, I want to resize casper loop file.
I have no problem following thoses steps :

1 - First I create a new bigger partition http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/

2 - After I transfert all data on this new partition as explained in this link [How do I transfer a casper-rw file to a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435320/how-do-i-transfer-a-casper-rw-file-to-a-partition)

3 - Then I use Qparted to erase the old partition

4 - And in the new partition, i enlarge the casper loop file http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/

But now, I can't boot on my usb key because partition id has changed
Partition type changed to : Fat32 replace by a Ext2.
- old was /dev/sdc1
- new is /dev/sdc2

I try 
     install-mbr /dev/sdc
I have a "mbr 2fa:" screen at start up, no boot is possible

Thank you for your help,
Francois

Answer (score 0):

I have found the right process : So i answer my question !

As i am beginner in Linux Persistence with Casper File, I will explain it in details. I think a lot of people who want for the first time make a big partition for persistence
will ask the same questions.

Here are my mistakes :

1 - When you use a Pen drive/Usb key,
    you have to keep FAT32 partition and create a second one Ext2 which while receive all files of casper-rw
    you can't boot without partition Fat32

2 - I have notice Gparted can break boot when partitions are modified (if fat32 resized or a new one created)

3 - When you copy files be careful of attributes files (use cp -a)

Here is the process :

1 - So First if you have already work with your usb pen drive, you need to save file casper-rw on an other disk

2 - Use an other instance of Linux to modify your Pen drive : Use Gparted to resize Fat32 partition, create the new one ext2.
    The Ext2 partition must be labeled casper-rw
    I have read Ext2 is better than Ext3 or Ext4 because Ext2 is not journalised, it's better for flash drive

3 - You should Have a flash drive with 2 partitions, one Fat32 of 1Go and an other Ext2 of 31Go for an USB key of 32 Go

4 - Use again Lili Usb Creator or other tool
    to reinstall your Iso but with a little file persistence : 200Mo for example

5 - boot one time on your pen drive to verify all works properly

6 - Use an other instance of Linux to modify your pen drive : The second partition ext2 will receive all the data stored in casper-rw but not the casper-rw file

```
  mount your save disk which contain the casper-rw file

  mount the casper-rw file

  mount the Ext2 partition labeled "casper-rw"

  copy with a "cp -a" all the files of the casper-rw container in the Ext2 partition

  -a option is important to preserve all the attribut of the files

  umount all your drive

  mount The fat32 partition and delete the casper-rw file

  umount the fat32 partition
```

7 - You can now use your pen drive